# App Engine deploy fails (Managed VM nodejs)

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

App Engine deploy fails with this error

```
Copying files to Google Cloud Storage...
Synchronizing files to [gs://staging.john-slowmo-droid-1116.appspot.com/].
Updating module [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [400] Invalid character in filename: node_modules/es5-ext/array/#/@@iterator/implement.js
```

This behavior did not happen before the second to latest gcloud update. Tried in gcloud sdk 0.9.86 and 0.9.87.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this; I'll direct it to the App Engine team. For now, you can work around pinning to a fixed version of the Cloud SDK as per [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/#alternative).

Comment: Also, the invalid character is `#`. Ironically, the Google Cloud Storage UI allows for a folder named `-#` but not `#` or `#abc`. Since es5-ext is well distributed in userland and is setup to have many modules in 1 lib, fixing this in the lib is not terribly easy and probably will break a lot of things. @ZacharyNewman

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a bug on the Google side. As soon as I have a tracking issue or an ETA for a fix I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks a ton @ZacharyNewman. If you could let me know what the expected behavior should be as soon as you can I'd appreciate it so I can plan for it when the fix lands.

Comment: It should look identical, except the last line, which should read `Updating module [default]...done`. There will also be one more line: `Deployed module [default] to [https://john-slowmo-droid-1116.appspot.com/`.

Comment: @ZacharyNewman so any filename is allowed? Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Correct, any file name should be allowed.

Comment: See [this tracking bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=392) for a workaround and updates on status.

Comment: Thanks @ZacharyNewman, I can confirm the workaround works, I just had an improperly formatted regex in my skip_files section for `node_modules`.